# Extracting a Clojure vec from a Jdbc4Array

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm very new to Clojure and I am working on creating a small web API using Clojure, Compojure and java.jdbc with a POSTGRES database.

One of my tables contains an array of integers as one of its columns and is defined as such:

```
                    (sql/create-table-ddl
                     :games
                     [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                     [:active :BOOLEAN "NOT NULL"]
                     [:players "integer[]" "DEFAULT array[]::integer[]"]
                     [:player_order "integer[]" "DEFAULT array[]::integer[]"]
                     [:created_at :timestamp
                      "NOT NULL" "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"])
```

I am trying to query for one of the integer[] as such:

```
(sql/query postgres  [(str "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id=" game-id)])
```

But POSTGRES returns a Jdbc4Array (instead of a vec):

```
:player_order #<Jdbc4Array {1,2,3,4}
org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
```

I can't seem to figure out how to turn this into a Clojure vec. I've seen a few examples but they seem to be using a stream which I am not. Am I doing this query incorrectly? How would I convert this to a Clojure vec?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the data returned with a call to `getResultSet`? You would use Java interop to do that.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Thanks for the idea. I've tried `.getResultSet` and `.getJavaArray` but I get this error when I do so: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.`

Answer (score 1):

`Jdbc4Array` implements `java.sql.Array`; I don't have a PG database or calling code to hand, but according to the docs for `java.sql.Array`, you should be able to call:

```
(into [] (.getArray your-val))
```

However, you shouldn't have to do that manually throughout your code. You can have the conversion from `Jdbc4Array` to Vector done automatically for you everywhere by extending the `clojure.java.jdbc/IResultSetReadColumn` protocol to `java.sql.Array`.

This has already been demonstrated here on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786990/152739

(I don't want to copy that guy's answer verbatim!)